# Trouble with extension attributes when pulling AAD user data in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to pull a detailed user report that my company can use for billing purposes with our clients. I am able to pull and gather most properties for each user to a csv file, but I am having trouble when it comes to Extension Attributes. In following the examples found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0), I wasn't able to make any progress. I'm hoping someone on here is knowledgeable and willing to walk me through what I'm missing. The code and error are below.

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential

# Get all Azure AD users
$AzADUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Select-Object -Property *


# Display progress bar
$progressCount = 0
for ($i = 0; $i -le $AzADUsers.Count; $i++) {

    Write-Progress `
        -Id 0 `
        -Activity "Retrieving User " `
        -Status "$progressCount of $($AzADUsers.Count)" `
        -PercentComplete (($progressCount / $AzADUsers.Count) * 100)
    $progressCount++
}

$UserId = (Get-AzureADUser -Searchstring $_.UserPrincipalName).ObjectId
    Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserId | Select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty
    pause
```

Gives me this error

Get-AzureADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ObjectId'.        Specified method is not supported.                                                                                      At C:\Users\James\OneDrive - Veeya\Desktop\O365 User License Reporting and Management\adcsv.ps1:22 char:28              +     Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserId | Select -ExpandProperty Extens ...

- ```
                            ~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser

Comment: @DougMaurer, unfortunately, `-All` is _not_ a `[switch]` parameter, but a `[bool]` parameter that therefore requires an explicit argument: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser

Comment: Your error message implies that `(Get-AzureADUser -Searchstring $_.UserPrincipalName).ObjectId` returned _multiple_ IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got same error:**

**Console:**
[image]

**Command:**

I tried the below commands which is executed with **`Extension property`** successfully.

```
Connect-AzureAD

# Get all Azure AD users
$AzADUsers = Get-AzureADUser

foreach($user in $AzADUsers)
{
    write-host "User Name :  " $user.DisplayName
    $UserId = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId  $user.UserPrincipalName).ObjectId
   Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserId | Select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty
   write-host " "
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

[image]

**Sample output for single user:**

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "< Object Id of user >" | Select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                                                         Value                                                                              
---                                                         -----                                                                              
odata.metadata                                              https://graph.windows.net/<>/$metadata#directo...
odata.type                                                  Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User                                                   
createdDateTime                                             04-01-2023 06:46:26                                                                
employeeId                                                                                                                                     
onPremisesDistinguishedName                                                                                                                    
userIdentities                                              []                                                                                 
extension_411567d7bfd94d2eb0f82xxxxxx_YourPropertyName YourPropertyValue
```

**Reference:**
[Azure AD cmdlets to work with extension attributes | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0#create-a-new-extension-property).